# Flowplayer cannot get autoplay working

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I have a div like so for containing flowplayer:

```
<div id="vidPlayer">
  <div class="flowplayer" id="flowplayer">
    <video autoplay>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="media/video/Lesson1.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is just a place holder. Later, I load a video into the player with JS like:

```
      var api = flowplayer();
      api.load([
        { mp4:  "media/video/Lesson2.mp4" },
        { webm: "media/video/Lesson2.webm" }
      ]);
```

The video loads fine, but I have to click it to begin play.

Comment: Actually all I did was add is-splash to the class like so:
<div class="flowplayer is-splash" >
and it autoplays all the videos now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
clip: { autoPlay: true }
```

Comment: Where does that go? Is it a property of api?